# compileAttributes doesn't copy the local header to RcppExports.cpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Here is my `R_API.cpp`

```
#include "include/R_GatingSet.hpp" 
#include <Rcpp.h>

Rcpp::List getPopCounts(Rcpp::XPtr<GatingSet> gsPtr, StringVec sampleNames, StringVec subpopulation, bool flowJo, bool isFullPath){
//do stuff
}
```

And here is `RcppExports.cpp` generated by `compileAttributes`

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// getPopCounts
Rcpp::List getPopCounts(Rcpp::XPtr<GatingSet> gsPtr, StringVec sampleNames, StringVec subpopulation, bool flowJo, bool isFullPath);
RcppExport SEXP flowWorkspace_getPopCounts(SEXP gsPtrSEXP, SEXP sampleNamesSEXP, SEXP subpopulationSEXP, SEXP flowJoSEXP, SEXP isFullPathSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    SEXP __sexp_result;
    {
        Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
        Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::XPtr<GatingSet> >::type gsPtr(gsPtrSEXP );
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< StringVec >::type sampleNames(sampleNamesSEXP );
}
```

Apparently this fails the compiler because it misses the local header include (`R_GatingSet.hpp`) that defines the user class `GatingSet`.

```
g++ -I/home/wjiang2/R/r-devel/build/include -DNDEBUG -DROUT -Wno-deprecated -I/home/wjiang2/mylib/include/libxml2  -Ibst/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/home/wjiang2/R/r-devel/build/library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
RcppExports.cpp:9:36: error: ‘GatingSet’ was not declared in this scope
```

I wonder if there is better solution other than manually adding this include back to `RcppExports.cpp`?

Comment: I have a somewhat recollection that this was discussed on rcpp-devel a few month ago.  Part of the problem is that non-R / non-Rcpp types (like `GatingSet`) are not usually exposed as you do not have any (default) converters.

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to handle this by having a header file of the same name as your package in (assuming the package is `flowWorkspace`):

```
inst/include/flowWorkspace.h
```

`compileAttributes` will include that header file in `RcppExports.cpp`, and in there you could include the definitions of classes you need for the rest of the exports machinery to work.

EDIT: You could also try using the `// [[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]` attribute to auto-generate these interfaces for you (although I haven't played around with that as much), but it is discussed in the [Rcpp Attributes vignette](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) -- see 3.5.1.

Comment: Bingo. This may even be documented in the vignette.

Comment: The side effect of copying the `c++` class definitions to `inst/include/flowWorkspace.h` is to expose them to `R` package users, which is fine in itself. But will it bring the trouble to the code maintenance?Since we now have two copies of `class definition` (another is in `src/include/`).

Comment: One option: use `configure` or `cleanup` to ensure the current version in `src/include` is copied to `inst/include`.

Comment: Just keep one copy only, and do `PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include` like everybody does, e.g. https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/src/Makevars